# Cornerstone isn't marking files as modified

Tags: svn, version-control, cornerstone

In Cornerstone v2.5.1.  I've imported a local folder into the repository.  I then selected Add Working Copy and selected this same local folder.  It now shows on the left side with a brown folder and lock on it, like all my other working copies.  The problem is that once I change any file i this folder, it is not flagged as modified and I cannot commit.

Did I do something wrong in this process or why isn't Cornerstone flagging changed files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing a folder into subversion repo doesn't make it a working copy unlike, say `hg init` (you can see this by navigating to the folder with Terminal and `ls -al`; notice the absence of .svn folders inside.) You need to now check out from the repository and then add the folder created by the checkout to Cornerstone.

Comment: Perfect!  But that is where it gets a little confusing for me.  I have local folder MyApp.  But when I checkout, it will want to be named something different or else overwrite the local folder. So I end up with two folders.  Can you explain how that is properly done?

Comment: I did go ahead and check out working copy and selected to merge with existing folder. I then changed content in one of the working copy files.  It still doesn't reflect in Cornerstone?

Comment: I'm not sure what the _merge with existing folder_ option does, but sounds like you have the wrong working copy folder in the Cornerstone browser. What happens if you launch Terminal, `cd` to the working copy folder where you made your changes and do a `svn status`? Does subversion list your changes?

Comment: This is what I'd do: Check out a new working copy with Cornerstone, don't use the merge option. Take the files you've modified and copy them to the new working copy you just checked out replacing the corresponding newly checked out files. Then check them in in Cornerstone.

Comment: That is mostly right but it is better to copy files within folders rather than overwriting folders.  Apparently when you overwrite folders, you overwrite the .svn related files.  This causes those folders to be locked and there isn't anything you can do to fix it.  Best thing is to start over, copying files rather than folders.

Comment: Indeed, never copy folders wholesale in a svn working copy. You'll nuke the .svn directories inside the working copy folders. Move files only.